# limited exec: can't assign new value to variable?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-exec

Having this code:

```
x = 10
exec('x += 5', {}, {'x': x})
print(x)  # prints 10.

# This works of course
exec('x += 5')
print(x)  # prints 15.
```

Why it does ignore my `x += 5` expression? Is there something else I remove, by limiting globals/locals on `exec`, so it does not allow to change variable?

P.S. Though it does work if I modify dictionary. Is it related with immutable types maybe?

Comment: If you wanted exec to use the actual scope it was in, why did you explicitly pass in a replacement scope?

Comment: @jonrsharpe didn't I pass scope I wanted to modify? I mean, all I want to modify is x, so I limit to that only.

Comment: That's not how scopes work. I'm not sure what your mental model is here, but reading https://nedbatchelder.com/text/names.html might help.

Comment: I didn't downvote, but generally people do because the question is unclear. In this case it was not clear why you were passing that scope at all.

Comment: @DanielRoseman I see. I was under impression it worked differently, than it actually was. Thats the reason I was passing it..:)

Comment: If you did `d = {"x": x}` then `d["x"] += 5`, would you expect that to change the result of `print(x)`?

Comment: @jonrsharpe no. thats not what I meant. I just passed dict variable to locals during `exec` and saw it change value for that dict. So I was under impression, the same would be for non mutable types. But for dict, it worked, because it was just a reference, so it would modify same dict anywhere (assuming it is not a copy)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's what is going on:

```
>>> x = 5
>>> loc = dict(x=x)
>>> exec('x += 5', {}, loc)
>>> print(loc)
{'x': 10}
>>> x
5
```

Comment: Oh I see. I was under impression, that after executing it, it will still add to real `globals`/`locals`. But it only saves it on specified dictionary.

Comment: Yes, that is the reason you can explicitly pass a replacement scope(/dictionary) ;-)